# ng-required with angular ui-ace

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

How would you implement ng-required together with angular ui-ace in a form?

This is my markup:

```
<form name="scriptform">
    <div name="script"
         ui-ace="{ onLoad: configureAce }"
         ng-required=""
         ng-model="someCodez">
    </div>
</form>

{{ scriptform }}
```

Out of the box it seems ace is not hooking up to the angular form validation framework,
since the {{ scriptform }} above is not printing out any form validation errors when
'someCodez' is null.

Comment: Currently I have a really ugly work around using aces "onChange" cb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glancing at the docs, I think the `ng-required` attribute only works together with the `<input>` element, so this approach might not be possible.

However, you can achieve similar results by changing the `$setValidity` of the form component itself. For example, when a user is no longer changing content in the Ace Editor:

```
$scope.configureAce = function() {
  return {
    onLoad: function (editor) {
      editor.on('blur', function() {
        if (/* test validity of someCodez */)
          $scope.scriptForm.script.$setValidity('scriptSyntax', true);
        else
          $scope.scriptForm.script.$setValidity('scriptSyntax', false);
        $scope.$digest();
      });
    }
  };
};
```

The first parameter to `$setValidity` is a custom string you can check for and f.e. use to display the error state to the user. See related docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: yep this is almost what I am doing. the editor events seem to be the only way to hook it up in the current version. thx for a good answer!